# Clone a tr, but preserve width

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, width, clone

I'm trying to clone a row in table, and insert this row into an empty table. Easy.

But is it possible to preserve the original width of the cells in the tr (that may perhaps be expanded due to other cells in the same column)?

**EDIT** Just realized I should iterate through the matching cells after the clone and sync the width. Still curious if there is a more direct way though...

Comment: Wait. . .  you want to have cells in the same columns to not share the same width? That seems odd.

Comment: @Levi Morrison Was I really that unclear? Fail on my part. I don't want to change anything about the table I am copying the row from. I want to copy the row, insert ONLY that row into a separate table (that will never contain any other rows but the one I copied), with identical width as before.

Comment: Ah, you want your tables to be the same width (and each column in that table), regardless of content?

Comment: @chrislegend , can you please provide some code

Comment: Why not work out the style sheet so the "original" table and the "destination" table are styled the same? (either through classes or hierarchy of elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clone your row, then iterate over the children of the row, setting the width of each child to each child of the original at the corresponding index.

```
var target = $('#target');
var target_children = target.children();

var clone = target.clone();

clone.children().width(function(i,val) {
    return target_children.eq(i).width();
});

$('<table>',{border:1}).append(clone).appendTo('body');
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/z7hWh/

I'm unsure of browser support for setting width on a `<td>`.

Comment: ...what if they resize their browser and the one table uses % and the other is now set?  uh-oh. . .

Comment: @Levi: Are we adding to the requirements? *"preserve the original width of the cells"* It doesn't say anything about syncing future changes to the widths.

Comment: Good solution. Thanks. It can be assumed that the table width won't change.

Answer (score 0):

**Specify strict CSS rules.**

**Possible answers:**

- Define them to be the same width for each cell *(probably not what you want)*.
- Use [colgroups](http://www.htmlite.com/lite037.php) *(recommended)*.
- Don't define styles for td's, but define them on the table head `th`.  Obviously doesn't work if you don't have a header to your tables.

Comment: Good ideas but I'd rather not touch the css or table structure too much (might break something else they have going), though this would definitely be the way to go

Comment: @chrislegend, eh, fine.  But this IS what CSS was made for. . . lol

Comment: For sure. I'm adding features to some pretty massive web apps... So I really sort of have to just 'go over top' of things as opposed to make significant changes.